# How to parse a series of strings with spaces in between in Lua

Tags: parsing, lua

I'm trying to parse a txt file which is in the format of **host-name IP mac-address** in Lua. All three separated with spaces, to try and then store it into a table using Lua.

I've tried doing this using :match function but can't see to get it to work.

```
function parse_input_from_file()
  array ={}
  file = io.open("test.txt","r")
  for line in file:lines() do
    local hostname, ip, mac = line:match("(%S+):(%S+):(%S+)")
    local client = {hostname, ip, mac}
  table.insert(array, client)
  print(array[1])
  end
end
```

It keeps on printing the location in memory of where each key/value is stored (I think).

I'm sure this is a relatively easy fix but I can't seem to see it.

Comment: you say spaces is a separator, then: `line:match("(.+)%s+(.+)%s+(.+)")`

Answer (score 2):

If hostname, ip and mac are separated by space your pattern may not use colons.
I added a few changes to store the captures in the client table.

```
function parse_input_from_file()
  local clients ={}
  local file = io.open("test.txt","r")
  for line in file:lines() do
    local client = {}
    client.hostname, client.ip, client.mac = line:match("(%S+) (%S+) (%S+)")
    table.insert(clients, client)
  end
  return clients
end

for i,client in ipairs(parse_input_from_file()) do
   print(string.format("Client %d: %q %s %s", i, client.hostname, client.ip, client.mac))
end
```

Alternatively:

```
local client = table.unpack(line:match("(%S+) (%S+) (%S+)"))
```

then `hostname` is `client[1]` which is not very intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

No colon in the regex:

```
local sampleLine = "localhost 127.0.0.1 mac123"
local hostname, ip, mac = sampleLine:match("(%S+) (%S+) (%S+)")
print(hostname, ip, mac) -- localhost 127.0.0.1 mac123
```

Comment: That's brilliant - I knew it was something as trivial as this. Do you know how I'm able to store this in an array/table. So if I had two sample Lines, it could store a list and within the list the table?

Comment: @Syn create a local table for each line `local tab = {} tab.hostName, tab.ip, tab.mac = sampleLinie:match("(%S+) (%S+) (%S+)")`  and put them into another table. if you don't care about string keys you can also use `local tab = table.pack(sampleLinie:match("(%S+) (%S+) (%S+)"))` of course.